# How do I edit the Workflow.PropertyInspectorview?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a beginner and rehosting a workflow designer and got some problem with WorkflowDesigner.PropertyInspectorView. I'm using my own execution engine.

My custom activities have two type of Attributes on its properties. [BDTParmIn] for input properties and [BDTParmOut] for output. I want to separate them in two different groups, but PropertyInspectorView group them together under misc.
  How to edit PropertyInspectorView to separate them out.
Here is its Image:
[image]
Where File is an Output property, but it cannot be identified by a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by adding another attribute to my properties. It is named as "CategoryAttribute" and present in System.ComponentModel.
I have also found another attribute named as DisplayNameAttribute that is also present in System.ComponentModel to change the display name of my properties by passing a string to it. Like 'ServiceName' into 'Service Name'[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHi3T.png)